# Mongoid Model relationship issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, mongoid, embed

I am trying to use mongoid_commentable to add comments to my documents. Everything is working ok, the only problem is in rails-admin (gem) I am getting the error "undefined method `rails_admin_default_object_label_method' for #". According to [other online discussions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1020) this error is related to relations between models.

My models are as follows and I can't work out exactly what I am doing wrong?

### Comment Model

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid_Commentable::Comment

  field :text, :type => String
  field :user_id, :type => String

  embedded_in :document, class_name: 'Document', inverse_of: 'comments_list'
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", inverse_of: 'comments_list'
end
```

### Document Model

```
class Document
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid_Commentable::Comment

...

  embeds_many :comments, class_name: 'Comment', inverse_of: 'comments_list'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

### User Model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid_Commentable::Comment

...

  has_many :comments, class_name: 'Comment', inverse_of: 'comments_list', :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

- edit -

I believe this issue may instead be related to mongoids "embeds_many" - see here for more info: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1547

Environment info:

Rails: 3.2.12
Mongoid: 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve this issue, so I decided to use active admin instead. Hopefully they fix this issue in future versions of Rails Admin

View this [github issue](https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid/issues/48#issuecomment-22049600).